# Can't ssh into an oracle database on Oracle Cloud Integration

Tags: oracle, cloud, terraform

I created the database using terraform with the following database system:

```
resource "oci_database_db_system" "test_db_system" {
  availability_domain = data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ADs.availability_domains[0].name
  compartment_id      = oci_identity_compartment.Compartment.id
  database_edition    = "STANDARD_EDITION"

  db_home {
    database {
      admin_password = var.db_password
      db_name        = "database"
      pdb_name       = "pdb"

      db_backup_config {
        auto_backup_enabled = false
      }
    }

    db_version   = "19.10.0.0"
    display_name = "MyTFDBHomeVm"
  }

  db_system_options {
    storage_management = "LVM"
  }

  shape                   = "VM.Standard2.2"
  subnet_id               = oci_core_subnet.ExampleSubnet.id
  ssh_public_keys         = [ file("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\.ssh\\PUBLIC_KEY_FILE") ]
  display_name            = "MyTFDBSystemVM"
  hostname                = "testhostname"
  data_storage_size_in_gb = 256
  license_model           = "BRING_YOUR_OWN_LICENSE"
  node_count              = 1
}
```

I then try to ssh into the database using the following command (I'm on Windows 10, using git bash). Public key comes from the nodes tab in the oci console.

```
ssh -i /c/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/PRIVATE_KEY oracle@PUBLIC_IP
```

I get the following error

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I have also tried generating a key in the OCI console and using that to connect also doesn't work. Last thing I tried was to ssh from a compute instance also being created, got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the wrong username! that's all, it should be opc so the ssh command should like

```
ssh -i /c/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/PRIVATE_KEY opc@PUBLIC_IP
```